# what is the equivalent of this javascript in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do we write Equivalent value of this in Jquery

```
document.getElementById( "selectbox").
options[document.getElementById("selectbox").selectedIndex].innerText;
```

Comment: Homework for a subject that teaches jQuery? That school must be pretty awesome.

Comment: @Bolt: The question seems so academic and constructed, I just had to ask. When in real life would you come up with this particular question?

Comment: @Tomalak: hmmm, it does. And I don't know either, I didn't when I was still learning the basics of jQuery.

Comment: does 'real life' actually matter if the question is good? perhaps the OP set themselves a contrived question in order to learn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple:

```
$('#selectbox option:selected').text();
```

Comment: The child selector is superfluous - select elements can't be nested. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: fine, I've eaten it now.

Answer (score 5):

You want to selected the selected `<option>` within the `<select id="selectbox">` tag and get its text:

```
$('#selectbox option:selected').text()
```

Because the selectbox can't really contain anything *but* options, you can omit that part:

```
$('#selectbox :selected').text()
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
$('#selectbox option:selected').text();
```

To get it on `change` event, you can do like this:

```
$('#selectbox').change(function(){
  alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The OPs Javascript example is unnecessarily repetitive and complex. It shows plain Javascript in a bad light compared to jQuery when in fact it should be simpler and more concise. This is really not something jQuery should be used for.

```
document.getElementById('selectbox').value;
```

Was that so hard? With the element reference stored in a variable it would be as simple as this

```
selectbox.value;
```

And For comparison, the jQuery code

```
$('#selectbox').val();
```

IMO the plain Javascript is more readable, direct, and certainly more performant.

I would hardly consider this question academic as the example code is so trivial; it does not involve DOM traversal and has no cross browser compatibility issues, which are the main things jQuery was designed to address. So what the point is I'm not really sure...

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP's Javascript outputs the `option` tags' text, not its value. See http://jsfiddle.net/VhRBd/1/. Your Javascript and jQuery versions are equivalent, but they're just not what was asked for.